# How to access an array with variables in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array that has variables. How do I access them?

The code that I used to set them up was:

```
Movie::Movie(string temp) {
    istringstream iS(temp);
    getline(iS, title, '\t');
    getline(iS, studio, '\t');
    iS >> releaseYear >> usRank >> usBoxOffice >> nonUSRank >>
          nonUSBoxOffice >> worldRank >> worldBoxOffice;

    void Movies::loadMovies(string fn) {
        ifstream iS(fn);
        string s;
        getline(iS, s); // Skip heading
        getline(iS, s);
        movieCnt=0;
        movies = new Movie[MAX_MOVIES];
        while(!iS.eof()) {
            movies[movieCnt++] = Movie(s);
            getline(iS, s);
        }
        iS.close();
        reSize();
    }
```

So if I wanted to access an array for the worldrank, would I just input `array[cnt].worldrank`?

Comment: I don't see any array in that code...

Comment: I don't see any array in that code either. Can you edit your question to clear up your question of what you are looking for?

Comment: isn't the 
            while(!iS.eof()) {  
            movies[movieCnt++] = Movie(s);
            getline(iS, s);
the array?

Comment: Yes, you can access the `Movie` class members from an array as you guessed (`movies[cnt].worldrank`). I'd use a `std::vector<Movie>` instead of the heap allocated array though.

Comment: how would you deference the array? i am getting a  error because i used a pointer for the array. i tried to do *movies[cnt].worldrank but it didn't help

Comment: @brianChiem `movies[cnt].worldrank` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: it does but they way i had it set up it uses a pointer for the array. i'm not sure how to dereference the array i tried to use {*movies[cnt].worldrank} but it didn't dereference it

Answer (score 0):

If the array contents are objects, you can do arrayname[index].variableofObject

if the array contents are POINTER to objects, then you do arrayname[index]->variableOfObject

That is it :)

Comment: By the way, that also apply to array of structures in C.